# How to remove date from footnote of madrid theme of beamer and use that space for extend title?

Tags: beamer

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
  \title{Function Reusing Based Task Distribution between Edge Cloud and Central Cloud in Hybrid CRAN}
  \author{Md.Al-Helal}

\vspace{1cm}
%\institute[CSEDU]{Computer Science \& Engineering\\University of Dhaka}
\date{July 29, 2018}
\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to fit the title in the footnote and use the date space in title removing date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the footer definition of this template, one finds:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{infolines theme}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
```

Since you want some bigger changes, I'd recommend to rewrite it:

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.15\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.77\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.08\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}%
    \hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
```

You can change the widths of those boxes that are set currently with `wd=.333333\paperwidth`.

In a MWE, including a slightly changed version for including the institution on page two:

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.15\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.77\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.08\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}%
    \hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \title{Function Reusing Based Task Distribution between Edge Cloud and Central Cloud in Hybrid CRAN}
  \author{Md.Al-Helal}


\date{July 29, 2018}
\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}

\institute[CSEDU]{Computer Science \& Engineering\\University of Dhaka}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.18\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.74\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.08\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}%
    \hspace*{1ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Choose one redefinition and put it in your preamble, maybe after some further modification.